# Pods stuck containercreating

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

previously my MySQL pod stuck at terminating status, and then I tried to force delete using command like this

`kubectl delete pods <pod> --grace-period=0 --force`

Later I tried to *helm upgrade* again, my pod was stuck at containercreating status, and this event from pod

```
17s         Warning   FailedMount   pod/db-mysql-primary-0     MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-f32a6f84-d897-4e35-9595-680302771c54" : kubernetes.io/csi: mount
er.SetUpAt failed to check for STAGE_UNSTAGE_VOLUME capability: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix
/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/dobs.csi.digitalocean.com/csi.sock: connect: no such file or directory"

17s         Warning   FailedMount   pod/db-mysql-secondary-0   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-61fc6eda-97fa-455f-ac2c-df8ebcb90f1c" : kubernetes.io/csi: mount
er.SetUpAt failed to check for STAGE_UNSTAGE_VOLUME capability: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix
/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/dobs.csi.digitalocean.com/csi.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
```

anyone please can help me to resolve this issue, thanks a lot.

Comment: This Github's issue could help you https://github.com/digitalocean/csi-digitalocean/issues/209

Comment: Could you describe your setup more in detail so that we know how to reproduce your issue on a test environment ? What helm chart do you use ? What about  `PVC`s mentioned in the error message ? Are they defined and available ?

Comment: @peterzinho16 thanks peter, i'll try to config Raw block volume mode on my cluster

Comment: @mario 

1. Setup mysql using helm, and PROVISIONER on my storageclass using DO (dobs.csi.digitalocean.com), so basically the mysql default installed from packaging helm chart, and then for volume using csi driver

2. my release helm chart using bitnami 

3. There is no error message from PVC, and the PVS is normal with bound phase

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command

```
kubectl delete pods <pod> --grace-period=0 --force
```

you ask kubernetes to forget the Pod, not to delete it. You have to be careful while using this command. You have to make sure that the containers of the Pod are not running in the host especially when they are mounted to a PVC. Probably the containers is still running and attached to the PVC.

Comment: but I have tried to re-deploy my db with a fresh pvc volume, but the error message from pod is CSI issues, it's sounds like csi socket not running on my nodes

Answer (score 0):

pool-product-8jd40    0

spec:
drivers: null

and on my some pool the driver csi not ready (null), it's supposed to be equal 1 (ready)

*sorry i can't attach the image yet